# How to decompose GCP gcloud Bash Script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm required to decompose the following gcloud bash script in different lines, starting each line with gcloud. The code I have to decompose is:

```
gcloud compute instances create myinstance-1 --project=[PROJECT_ID] --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --network-interface=subnet=default,no-address --metadata=enable-oslogin=true --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE --provisioning-model=STANDARD --service-account=[SERVICE_ACCOUNT]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=myinstance-1,image=projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20221102,mode=rw,size=10,type=projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/us-central1-c/diskTypes/pd-balanced --no-shielded-secure-boot --shielded-vtpm --shielded-integrity-monitoring --reservation-affinity=an
```

I did manage to do the first as follows:

```
gcloud compute instances create myinstance-1 --project=[PROJECT_ID] --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --network-interface=subnet=default
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried

```
gcloud compute instances create myinstance-1 --project=[PROJECT_ID] --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --network-interface=subnet=default
```

This part works but I'm clueless for the other part.

I did figure it and it worked:
Thank you all

```
#!/bin/bash

#utility virtual machine

gcloud compute disks create disk-1 --size=10GB --zone=us-west1-a
gcloud compute instances create myinstance-1 \ 
--zone=us-west1-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1
gcloud compute instances attach-disk myinstance-1 --disk=disk-1 \ --zone=us-west1-a
gcloud compute networks create myinstance-1-network
gcloud compute firewall-rules create myinstance-1-firewall \ --network myinstance-1-network --allow tcp,udp,icmp --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0

#Windows virtual machine

gcloud compute disks create disk-2 --size=10GB --type=pd-ssd \ --zone=us-west1-a
gcloud compute instances create windows-instance --zone=us-west1-a \ --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --image=windows-server-2016-dc-core-v20221109 --image-project=windows-cloud --boot-disk-size=100GB
gcloud compute instances attach-disk windows-instance \ --disk=disk-2 --zone=us-west1-a
gcloud compute networks create windows-instance-network
gcloud compute firewall-rules create windows-instance-firewall \ --network windows-instance-network --allow tcp,udp,icmp --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0

#Custom virtual machine

gcloud compute disks create disk-3 --size=10GB --zone=us-west1-a
gcloud compute instances create myinstance-3 --zone=us-west1-a \ --machine-type=e2-medium --image=debian-10-buster-v20220118 \ --image-project=debian-cloud --boot-disk-size=10GB
gcloud compute instances attach-disk myinstance-3 --disk=disk-3 \ --zone=us-west1-a
gcloud compute networks create myinstance-3-network
gcloud compute firewall-rules create myinstance-3-firewall --network myinstance-3-network \ --allow tcp,udp,icmp --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: The request is "unusual". The script comprises a single `gcloud` command and I'm unsure of any benefit in trying to decompose this into (simpler?) steps. All (the majority of?) flags add specificity to the request e.g. which machine type to use rather than assume a default etc. One thing you can try (!) is to run the original command and append `--log-http`. This will show you what underlying REST API calls are being made by `gcloud` to effect `gcloud compute instances create` and this would then help you identify a multi-step way to perform this otherwise single-step command.

Comment: What does **decompose** mean in your question?

Comment: You can create the boot disk first, etc but as Daz says, what’s the point of doing this? For me this seems like an XY problem

Comment: @DazWilkin @Ferragina Actually, I did figure out, and did it as follows, and it worked the way they wanted it:`